# Deleting record from file

Tags: c++, file

So I have a record of students for instance:

```
name,age,contact
name2,age2,contact2
name3,age3,contact3
```

Task is to delete record by searching name. Problem is my code deletes the whole data starting from name search. Like, if I have to delete record of name2, the data should be:

```
name,age,contact
name3,age3,contact3
```

But my code does:

```
name,age,contact
```

thus deleting the whole data present downwards of it if it finds the name. Been stuck at this problem.. 
Here is the code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
            char names[30], search[30], contact[30];
            int i = 0, j = 0, age=0;
            bool flag;
            cout << "Enter name from records : ";
            cin.ignore();
            cin.getline(search, 19);
            ifstream fin;
            fin.open("studentinfo.txt");
            ofstream fout;
            fout.open("output.txt");
            if (fin.is_open())
            {
                while (!fin.eof())
                {
                    flag = true;
                    fin.getline(names, 19, ',');
                    fin >> age;
                    fin.ignore();
                    fin >> contact;
                    fin.ignore();
                    if (names[i] == search[j])
                    {
                        while (names[i] == search[j] && names[i] != ',' && search[j] != '\0')
                        {
                            i++;
                            j++;
                        }

                        if (search[j] == '\0')
                        {
                            flag = false;
                        }
                    }
                    else if(flag == true)
                        fout << names << ',' << age << ',' << contact << endl;
                }
                fin.close();
                fout.close();
            }

            else
            {
                cout << "file not found \n" << endl;
                return 0;
            }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems in your code.

The first (and, perhaps, most obvious) is that you are not resetting `i` and `j` to zero at the start of each of the `while` loops - which means that your `if (names[i] == search[j])` will be comparing two characters that are (possibly) beyond the end of the given `names` input (and also the `search` string) on all records after which a match has been found. **Solution:** set `i` and `j` to zero at the beginning of *each* `while` loop, in the same way as you reset `flag`. (Further, it is unclear to me why you need two different variables, here: `i` and `j` will always have the same value, so just use one and discard the other).

A second problem is the line `else if(flag == true)`. This means that, once the **first** character of a name matches the first character of the search (i.e. the associated `if (names[i] == search[j])` block has been entered), then you will not be writing that record to the output file. **Solution:** remove the `else` word - you are testing if a *complete* match has been found by setting `flag` to false, so you need to test that *even if the preceding `if` block has been entered, and not found a complete match*.

As a further 'improvement', you could actually declare the `i`, (`j`, ) `age` and `flag` variables inside the `while` loop, setting their initial values in those declarations.

Comment: You just made me feel incredibly stupid.. I put i and j inside the loop and it works correctly. Been working on it since an hour and it was just because I was not resetting values of i and j.. Thanks, it worked!

Answer (score 1):

Seems as you have couple of issues:

1. First call to `cin.ignore` results in discarding the first input character, which you probably don't want.
2. Why do you need both `i` and `j`? seems as you need only one of them, and it should equal 0 at the beginning of each loop iteration.
3. `else if (flag == true)`. The `else if` is checked only if the previous condition was not met, but if it was not met, then `flag` is necessarily `true`. Change it to `if (flag == true)`, or simply `if (flag)`
4. Don't `using namespace std`

Good luck!

Edit: I applied the fixes, and added a check after every Input/Output (IO) operation. the code as follows:

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>

int main()
{
    char names[30], search[30], contact[30];
    int i = 0, age = 0;
    bool flag;

    std::cout << "Enter name from records : ";
    std::cin.getline(search, 19);

    std::ofstream fout("output.txt");
    if (!fout) {
        std::cout << "Failed opening output file" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    std::ifstream fin("studentinfo.txt");
    if (!fin) {
        std::cout << "file not found" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    while (!fin.eof())
    {
        i = 0;
        flag = true;
        fin.getline(names, 19, ',');
        fin >> age;
        fin.ignore();
        fin >> contact;
        fin.ignore();
        if (!fin) {
            std::cout << "Failed reading from file" << std::endl;
            return 2;
        }
        if (names[i] == search[i])
        {
            while (names[i] == search[i] && names[i] != ',' && search[i] != '\0')
            {
                i++;
            }

            if (search[i] == '\0')
            {
                flag = false;
            }
        }
        if (flag) {
            fout << names << ',' << age << ',' << contact << std::endl;
        }
    }

    fin.close();
    fout.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit. About the cin.ignore(), if I don't use it, it just won't take input rather it will skip it and go to the next line of code..

Answer (score 0):

Simplest approach (IMHO):

Read the entire file into memory.
Edit what needs to be edited (*in memory*). Then overwrite the old file with the new content (or, write to new file, delete old file and then atomically rename new file to old file name).

You cannot insert (or delete) data in the middle of a file. You can only either overwrite existing data with same length or rewrite the file.

Comment: OP is *not* deleting data from the input file - rather trying to write all (except one) record from the input to the output.